# How to upload files through laravel api routes

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am creating an api to upload files. It works when I upload them through web routes file, but it doesn't work when I upload them through api routes file.

```
axios.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
axios.put('/api/pikirler', formData);
```

If I change it to:

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
axios.post('/upload', formData);
```

It works fine. But I want to use it in api routes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use guzzle package in your controller. Following is the code to upload file with guzzle.

```
$options = [
      'multipart' => [
        [
          'name' => 'user_key'
        ],
        [
          'name' => 'file_names',
          'contents' => '[]'
        ],
        [
          'name' => 'file',
          'contents' => file_get_contents($filePath),
          'filename' => $fileName,
          'headers'  => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream'
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ];

      $httpClient = new GuzzleClient();
      $response   = $httpClient->request("POST", "someApiUrl", $options);
```

Following is the documentation.
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/overview.html

Comment: Can't I just upload it with axios by changing headers?

Comment: I didnt try axios. @AzatAkmyradov. I normally use guzzle.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out. But it would be good if I will found out how to do it with axios

Comment: OP is talking about posting from the client side, using axios, which is javascript. This answer is talking about using guzzle from the server side using PHP. Quite irrelevant. OP I believe the API routes only expect json data. You want to change it to accept multipart/form-data, this may be changeable somewhere in laravel, I have yet to find where. Or just use JSON from axios instead of form data